# If td paragraph has class, hide tr class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide

I need to hide (`display:none;`) an entire `<tr>` if the paragraph contained within the `<td>` has a specific class.

Example:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="sample-34457" class="row-class">
            <td class="cell-class"></td>
            <td class="cell-class"></td>
            <td class="cell-class">
                <p class="hide-tr-if-class"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried some methods using CSS but it doesn't work 100% of the time.

Some jQuery I have tried:

```
if ($("p").hasClass(".hide-tr-if-class") ) {
    $("tr#sample-*").hide();

    ///// OR

    $(".row-class").css("display"`, "none");

};
```

No real luck with either attempt. My goal is to hide the entire table row using display:none if the paragraph has the class. This will remove items from a list in the end if conditions are met.

Thanks.

Comment: are the rows generated dynamically?

Comment: Yes that's why I put the wildcard. They have a taxonomy like in the code above. I just used a random number.

Comment: can you post the code that generate the rows as well? The code that hides the rows needs to be run every time a new row is added.

Comment: To hide it's `closest` tr having id **sample**

Comment: `$( "p.hide-tr-if-class" )
  .closest( "tr" )
  .css( "display", "none" );`

Would that work?

Comment: @ben.kaminski yes. BTW `.css( "display", "none" );` is the same as `.hide()`, so use `hide` as it is shorter and clearer. Also, you need to run it after the rows have been generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you use `hasClass`, the parameter will not need a `.`

Moreover, use `closest` to select the closest parent (here `tr`)

```js
if ($('p').hasClass('hide-tr-if-class')) {
  console.log('in here')
  $('p.hide-tr-if-class').closest('tr').css('visibility', 'hidden');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="sample-34457" class="row-class">
      <td class="cell-class">a</td>
      <td class="cell-class">b</td>
      <td class="cell-class">
        <p class="hide-tr-if-class">c</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sample-34457" class="row-class">
      <td class="cell-class">d</td>
      <td class="cell-class">e</td>
      <td class="cell-class">
        <p class>f</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This worked great. I just changed the CSS to "display", "none" and I get the desired result. THANKS!!!

Comment: If you are going to use `$('p.hide-tr-if-class')` then the `if` statement is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the `tr` ancestor of the `p` element, then hide it like so:

```
$("p.hide-tr-if-class")  // select the 'p' elements with the class 'hide-tr-if-class', the 'if' statement is not needed here
  .closest("tr")         // get their closest 'tr' ancestors
  .hide();               // hide them, this is equivalent to '.css( "display", "none" )' but shorter and clearer
```

**Note:** If the rows are added dynamically, then the above code needs to be executed after the generating code is done.

Comment: Unfortunately, using .hide(); leaves the elements present in the HTML output. So there are large spaces between list items. Using CSS display, none works here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($("p").hasClass(".hide-tr-if-class") ) {
   $(this).closest('tr').hide();
{
```